# In MongoDB, if document is removed, index removed automatically as well?

Tags: java, mongodb

I've a collection say "mails". I've bulk insertion to that collection and I need to remove the document after processing from the collection. And I've indexes to that collection. If I remove the document does that index also removed??

Answer (score 0):

When a document is removed from a collection, the index *entries* for that document are removed, but the index *itself* remains, even when you delete all documents it references. To delete an index, use [`db.collection.dropIndex`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.dropIndex/)